# .REP and/or .WID Runtime Engine - Business Objects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Is there any kind of runtime engine for Business Objects .REP and/or .WID files? I have been searching, but I have not found anything.

NOTE: I am not referring to .RPT and/or Crystal Reports

For example, if I wanted to open a .REP report within in a .Net application, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing will happen on the server for WID files, but there is a ReportEngine for processing them.

I am not familiar with .NET but the Java code is as such:

```
// acquire your enterpriseSession via your preferred route.
IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession;

// begin retrieval of ReportEngine
ReportEngines engines = (ReportEngines)enterpriseSession.getService("ReportEngines");
ReportEngine webiReportEngine = engines.getService(ReportEngines.ReportEngineType.WI_REPORT_ENGINE);

// Use the ReportEngine to open a document
DocumentInstance docInstance = webiReportEngine.openDocument(obj.getID());
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I did not specify .Net in my question (I should have). Since now one else has answered, I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer.